# insertHTML with hidden element

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, ecmascript-5

I need confirmation please!

I am trying to swap out the contents from one element to another that includes HTML tags.  I am pretty sure I am correct when stating the below code should work. I need to know if I am right though because if the reason for this not working is what I think it is, I have some additional functions I will need to create.

Please confirm this is correct or wrong:

```
function subNavContent ( ) {  

    var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName( 'pageNav' ).innerHTML;

    document.getElementById( 'subNav' ).innerHTML = navContent;}
```

Calling from:

```
<div class="pageNav">
    <h1 data-title="Welcome to The Mind Company"><a>Welcome</a></h1>
</div>
```

Sending to:

```
    <nav id="subNav" class="aniSubNavOpen drop-shadow lifted">
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute these two lines:

```
var navSub = document.getElementById( 'subNav' ).innerHTML;
var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName( 'pageNav' )[0].innerHTML;
```

You are getting the HTML text from those two objects and storing it in two variables.  You now have two regular javascript variables, each with a string in them.

When you then do:

```
navSub = navContent;
```

You are just assigning the navContent string to the navSub javascript variable.  It won't affect the DOM in any way.  These are just two string variables.

If you wanted to change the contents of the navSub object in the DOM, you could do this:

```
var navSubObj = document.getElementById( 'subNav' );
var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName( 'pageNav' )[0].innerHTML;
navSubObj.innerHTML = navContent;
```

Also, note that I had to change this:

```
var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName( 'pageNav' ).innerHTML;
```

to this:

```
var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName( 'pageNav' )[0].innerHTML;
```

because `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, not an object (as it can return multiple items).  It's different than `getElementById()` in this regard because `getElementById()` only returns one object.

Comment: hmm, sounds reasonable. But then `.innerHTML` is a getter method underneath ? I mean, what is it. It acts strange, you can't copy a reference to the property to shortcut ?

Comment: In javascript, `.innerHTML` acts like a property of the object.  You can set it or you can get it and the implementation internally will do the right thing when you get or set that property.  You can't get a reference to the `.innerHTML` property itself.  It gets the current value of the property, not a reference to it.

Comment: that is not correct. It depends on the type from the property. You will of course get a reference if there is an `object` behind a property. But you're right about primitive values.

Comment: but it feels wrong'ish in this case nonetheless. Because this property, not only is a simple text reference, its change reflects directly on a living DOM node. That's why I thought this is a setter method internally.

Comment: @jAndy - Of course, there are setting and getter method implementations underneath the `.innerHTML` property inside the actual implementation, but they didn't give you direct access to those methods.  If they wanted you to have access to those methods, they would have made methods `.setInnerHTML()` and `.getInnerHTML()`, but they didn't implement it that way.  Some properties are not really properties, but pseudo properties with getter and setter methods underneath.

Comment: got it.  Had to change from a class to a id for some unknown reason(figure it out later).

Comment: @BrandonClark - `document.getElementsByClassName( 'pageNav' )` returns an array, not an object, so your code would need to be `document.getElementsByClassName( 'pageNav' )[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you.  I mentioned you in my fix.  Hate the new user thing of stack, too long to give people a answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong.

It seems like `.innerHTML` is internally some kind of a `setter` which means, you're loosing the Context when copy the reference (at least in FF12).

This will work:

```
document.getElementById( 'subNav' ).innerHTML = navContent;
```

Comment: I believe I understand.  See above changes to code.  There seems to be no information being passed still according to 'console.log'.

Comment: Had to change from a class to a id for some unknown reason(figure it out later).

Answer (score 1):

NavSub is the text of the innerHTML. Make navSub the object then navSub.innerhtml = ... (sorry for poor use of caps, i'm on my phone). Comment if you don't get what I mean.

Comment: Still having issues.  Made a corrections as suggested (I believe I understand what you were saying. ).  This is my console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property of 'innerHTML' to NULL.

Comment: Had to change from a class to a id for some unknown reason(figure it out later).

Comment: imho, as with "english vs math", javascript is incompatible with some peoples' minds. I'm one of those people. When jQuery came along, it's like a light bulb went off. I consider the use of jQuery and Firebug to be mandatory. :) The class vs id issue is matter of ambiguity or improper DOM navigation. Here, too, I always use id and don't trust class.

Comment: Not sure what you insinuating about me there but I pulled off something pretty nice with having no JavaScript background in 2 weeks.    Still have a couple issue regarding this particular issue to how I planned on doing things in my head. Here is what I have done with this: [The Mind Company](http://www.themindspot.com)

Comment: Knowing the core issues behind the language is important and jQuery will not be around forever, its only a library that references things that exist in JavaScript to assist in making things easier (not better).  If I was concerned with backwards browser compatibility I may consider use of such library if this was for a job to quicken the completion time.  But I still would want to know the principle of the stuff and how it is limited or not.

Comment: That roll-up animation you do is quite nice! I'm definitely not a fan of flashy/snazzy and I like what you did, so great job with that design. :)